# dilutions in bacterial culture

Tags: lab-techniques, cell-culture

In overnight bacterial culture, why do we put bacteria in a small flask to culture before moving it to a larger flask? Why not just put the sample in a large flask to begin with? This is in reference to growing e. coli to produce proteins in a 125mL flask overnight first, then over a liter after that. For recombinant protein expression.

Comment: Not sure, but it may have to do with equalizing/standardizing the size of the initial innoculum for the large culture.  Normally you want to harvest the large flask while it is still growing in log phase or otherwise appropriate condition. If your initial innoculum varies widely in number of cells, time to harvest of the large flask can also vary substantially. It might also have to do with maintaining selection for a plasmid, as partially permissive culture conditions under many generations can lead to selection for faster growth/loss/deletion of plasmid.

Comment: @Val Can you please give a specific example of a protocol you're working with? With what you've written right now, there's too much unknown to be able to answer your question clearly.